# How can I resolve the error of req.body.name undefined in express JS?

Tags: node.js, express

I am doing this like. I am doing this in MVC pattern. Kindly suggest proper way to do signup in MVC pattern.

```
var userModel = require('../models/userModel');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var data = {

    name : req.body.name,
    email : req.body.email,
    number : req.body.number,
    address : req.body.address,
    password : req.body.password

}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a route so there's no request to access the `body`. You're also not listening to any requests.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
};

app.listen(3000);
```